# Scrollview being duplicated when tab focused

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm getting my data from an SQLite database and showing the data when the tab is focused. The problem is that the Scrollview displaying the data is being duplicated whenever I move to another tab. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._subscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      this.retrieveSavedCards();
    });

  }
```

This is how I'm retrieving the data

```
  retrieveSavedCards(){
    db.transaction(
      tx => {
       tx.executeSql('select * from MyScannedCards', [], (trans, result) => {
        var len = result.rows.length;
        for (i=0;i<len;i++){
          cardDetails = result.rows._array[i];
          this.setState({ cardholders: this.state.cardholders.concat(cardDetails) })
        }
        });
      }
    );
```

}

This is my scrollview and how the data is supposed to be displayed:

```
<ScrollView>
  {
    this.state.cardholders.map((l, i) => (
      <ListItem
        key={i}
        leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: this.state.baseUrl+l.avatar } }}
        title={l.cardholderfirstname + " " + l.cardholderlastname}
        subtitle="Your company"
        onPress={() => {
          this.toggleModal();
        }}
      />

    ))
  }
   </ScrollView>
```

This is my state:

```
this.state = {
  cardholders: [

  ],
  baseUrl: "http://myurl.com"     
};
```

Comment: Because your component is mounted everytime you move to another tab and its call  `componentDidMount`, caused by the `didFocus ` event listener. Try to unsubscribe  the event at `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a hack, but I couldn't figure out how to stop the scrollview from duplicating so instead I made the scrollview stop displaying an object already in state.

In my for loop:

```
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
      cardDetails = result.rows._array[i];
      console.log(cardDetails.id)
      this.addUser(cardDetails);
    }
```

And then additional functionality to check for duplicates and update state if something new is found.

```
 userExists(cardDetails) {
    return this.state.cardholders.some(function(el) {
      return el.id === cardDetails.id;
    }); 
  }

  addUser(cardDetails) {
    if (this.userExists(cardDetails)) {
      console.log("Skipping")
      return false; 
    }
    this.setState({ cardholders: this.state.cardholders.concat(cardDetails) })
    console.log("Adding")
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to unmount the `didFocus` event listener.
As mentioned here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/status-bar.html#tabnavigator

```
componentWillUnmount() {
this._subscribe.remove();
}
```